# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoModulesCore.NativeModulesProxy.ExpoSplashScreen')

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-splash-screen, expo-core-modules

I am getting this issue in react native. The things were working fine until I decicded to rerun the project doing `yarn install`

Here is complete error

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoModulesCore.NativeModulesProxy.ExpoSplashScreen')
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
> at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
> at node_modules\expo-error-recovery\build\ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
> at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
> at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:294:29 in invoke
> at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
> at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:155:27 in invoke
> at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:165:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
> at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
> at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue

I have tried with update expo-cli, expo-splash-screen and with cache clear command expo r -c

Let me know if there is anyone who can help.

Comment: You are use Macbook too?

Comment: I was using expo go only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can show warnnigs of log? Because i have the same problem and resolved with.

Logs:

- expo-app-loading - expected version: 1.1.2 - actual version installed: 1.3.0
- react-native-screens - expected version: ~3.4.0 - actual version installed: 3.10.1

I used the versions 1.1.2 and 3.4.0 in my package:
`"react-native-screens": "^3.4.0"` to `"react-native-screens": "3.4.0"`
`"expo-app-loading": "^1.1.2"` to `"expo-app-loading": "1.1.2"`

Remove your node_modules, yarn.lock and package-lock.json

```
Yarn install 
# or 
npm install
```

For me resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I was having issues with **expo-web-browser**. So, just simply clear your cache with the following command on your terminal. You will not see errors like above again:

> expo r -c